# How to copy text inside Virtual Machine using Automation Anywhere bot?

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

Steps:

1. Need to login to the Virtual Machine. Done
2. Open Notepad
3. Copy the text

Please let me know your feasible ways.

Comment: What do you have problems with? Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

Send Keys Should Do:

1. Ctrl + R
2. "Notepad"
3. Enter
4. Ctrl + V